# Python, convert flac file's channel

Tags: python, channel, google-speech-api, flac

I want to convert the channel of flac files. Because I'm now using google cloud speech to recognition audio files. I have .Flac files but i can't achieve my goal because that files are encoded in Channel 2. Google doesn't support the Channel '2' flac files. So I have to convert the channel 2 to 1. Is there any API about the covert channel? I want to see some example. Thanks for reading, and here is my code.

```
audio = types.RecognitionAudio(content=content)
config = types.RecognitionConfig(
encoding='FLAC',
sample_rate_hertz=48000,
language_code='ko-KR',

)
```

Comment: try ffmpeg ... https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/AudioChannelManipulation